# attributeerror module django db models has no attribute

Tags: python, django

Every time showing this problem...
attributeerror module django db models has no attribute

Please help me.

`from django.db import models
class Student(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    age = models.CharField(max_length = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    age = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
```